# iPhone Settings.bundle textfield preference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, settings.bundle

How would I make an option in Settings.bundle which allows the user to select what type of textfield preference they would like? Example: selecting if they want autocompletion on or off.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you'd use a toggle switch to turn autocompletion on or off, no? Read @Fran's linked document to find out how to include one in your Root.plist file.